# Configuring CodeIgniter with PDT

Tags: php, codeigniter, eclipse-pdt

I am using the codeIgniter as my base framework and the PDT as the IDE. I am quite habitual of using code-completion feature. I couldn't find a way to have this feature work in PDT for codeIgniter..
Say if I write `$this->load->` it dosen't do anything...

Anyone who has configured this?

Answer (score 0):

I hope [this](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/69098/#365282) helps.

Comment: I know. It seems that it's the best solution, for now.